# Spark filter dataframe returns empty result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working in a project with Scala and Spark processing files that are stored in HDFS. Those files are landing in HDFS everyday in the morning. I have a job that reads that file from HDFS each day, process it and then writes the result in HDFS. After I convert the file into a Dataframe, this job executes a filter to get only the rows that contain a timestamp higher than the highest timestamp that was processed within the last file. This filter has an unknown behavior only some days. Some days works as expected and other days despite of the new file contains rows that match that filter, the filter result is empty. This happens all the times for the same file when it's executed in TEST environment but in my local works as expected using the same file with the same HDFS connection.

I've tried to filter in different ways but none of then work in that environment for some specific files but all of then work fine in my LOCAL:
1) Spark sql

```
val diff = fp.spark.sql("select * from curr " +
s"where TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(substring(${updtDtCol}, 
${substrStart},${substrEnd}),'${dateFormat}') as TIMESTAMP))" +
s" > TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('${prevDate.substring(0,10)}' 
,'${dateFormat}') as TIMESTAMP))")
```

2) Spark filter functions

```
val diff = df.filter(date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col(updtDtCol),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat).gt(date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col("PrevDate"),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat)))
```

3) Adding extra column with the result of the filter and then filter by this new column

```
val test2 = df.withColumn("PrevDate", lit(prevDate.substring(0,10)))
      .withColumn("DatePre", date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col("PrevDate"),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat))
      .withColumn("Result", date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col(updtDtCol),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat).gt(date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col("PrevDate"),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat)))
      .withColumn("x", when(date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col(updtDtCol),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat).gt(date_format(unix_timestamp(substring(col("PrevDate"),0,10),dateFormat).cast("timestamp"),dateFormat)), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))

val diff = test2.filter("x == 1")
```

I think that the issue is not caused either by the filter itself or probably by the file but I would like to receive feedback about what should I check or if anybody has faced this before.

Please let me know what information could be useful to post here in order to receive some feedback.

A part of file example looks like the following:

```
|TIMESTAMP                 |Result|x|
|2017-11-30-06.46.41.288395|true  |1|
|2017-11-28-08.29.36.188395|false |0|
```

The TIMESTAMP values are compared with the previousDate (for instance: 2017-11-29) and I create a column called 'Result' with the result of that comparison that always works in both environment and also another column called 'x' with the same result.

As I mentioned before, if I use the comparator function between both dates or the result in column 'Result' or 'x' to filter the dataframe, sometimes the result is an empty dataframe but in local using the same HDFS and file, the result contains data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody wants to know what happened with this issue and how I finally found the cause of the error here is the explanation. Basically it was caused by the different timezone of the machines where the job was executed (LOCAL machine and TEST server). The unix_timestamp function returned the correct value having in mind the timezone of the servers. Basically at the end I didn't have to use the unix_timestamp function and I didn't need to use the full content of the date field. Next time I will double check this before.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it to be a data/date format issue. Did you get a chance to verify if the dates converted are as expected?

If the date string for both the columns has timezone included, the behavior is predictable.

If only of one of them has timezone included, the results will be different when executed in local and remote. It totally depends on timezone of cluster.

For debugging the issue, I would suggest you to have additional columns to capture the unix_timestamp(..)/millis of the respective date strings and have and additional column to capture the difference of the two columns. The diff column should help to find out where and why conversions gone wrong. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good approach but I have just added more info that confirm that I can use the same query or function to create a new column with the result as a boolean that always works fine but when I use the same query or function or even the value of the new columns to filter the dataframe sometimes doesn't work.